# JavaScript: last value printed in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Is there an equivalent to the Python `_` in JavaScript referencing the last value printed in the console?

I'm especially interested in Chrome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Chrome and Firefox, you can use `$_`. It references the return value from the last evaluation.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/YDkYV/ How can I print the last value that was printed?

Comment: I think this is the last expression evaluated in the console, and not just anything that was printed with `console.log`, unfortunately.

Comment: Just noting that this works in Mozilla Firefox too (tested on version 39).